# How to link url parameter with returned data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am sending an http request to my server for every name that I have. The name is sent as a request parameter and returning data specific to that name, however, the data returned does not come back with the associated name. I am trying to make a table with the data but I have no way of linking the name to the data returned.

```
class Campaigns extends Component {

    state = {
        campaigns: [
            {
                name: 'intelligent dentistry - oklahoma city'
            },
            {
                name: 'intelligent dentistry - cincinnati'
            },
            {
                name: 'intelligent dentistry - sanford'
            },
            {
                name: 'intelligent dentistry - louisville'
            },
            {
                name: 'intelligent dentistry - austin'
            }
        ],

        campaignData: []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        let campArray = []
        this.state.campaigns.forEach((campaign, i) => {
            let encodedName = encodeURIComponent(campaign.name.trim())
            axios.get(`/api/campaign/${encodedName}`).then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data.data)
                campArray.push(res.data.data)
                this.setState({
                    campaignData: [...campArray]
                })


            })
        })
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state.campaignData)

        let campaignTableData = this.state.campaignData.map((campaign, i) => (
            <>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>{campaign.totals.visits}</td>
                <td>{campaign.totals.contacts ? campaign.totals.contacts : '0'}</td>
                <td>{campaign.totals.customers ? campaign.totals.customers : '0'}</td>
            </tr>
            </>
        ))
```

Returned Data -

```
totals:
bounceRate: 1
bounces: 2
pageviewsPerSession: 1
rawViews: 2
visits: 2
```

Endpoint that I am hitting -

```
app.get('/api/campaign/:campaign', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params)
axios.get(`https://api.hubapi.com/analytics/v2/reports/utm-campaigns/total?hapikey=test&d1=${req.params.campaign}`).then((response) => {
        let json = CircularJSON.stringify(response)
        res.status(200).send(json)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})
```

Comment: So you just want to insert the response data into the corresponding object in the campaigns array?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

You could tack on the name yourself when you're setting your state since you already know it. One other issue with your code is that you're currently overwriting your state.campaignData on every single request instead of adding onto it. You'll want to merge in the previous state of campaignData as well.

```
this.setState(previousState => ({
  campaignData: [ ...previousState.campaignData, { ...campArray, name: campaign.name }]
}));

...

<td>{campaign.name}</td>
<td>{campaign.totals.visits}</td>
```